# Extracting values from array created with FeatureClassToNumPyArray and converted to DataFrame?

Tags: arcpy, numpy, array, pandas

I cannot understand how to use the values in the arrays created with arcpy.FeaturesToNumPyArray.

I want to create an array and then convert them to a pandas DataFrame. So I created an array from FeaturesToNumPyArray and tried to extract "SHAPE@XY" values. But the problem is the values are stored in some kind of 2 dimensional arrays. I thought it would be easy to split them vertically with numpy.vsplit but Python tells that the array is not a 2 dimensional.

If possible I would like to covert all table values into a DataFrame, and then use for some calculations because I think that would be easy to calculate and easy to see the codes afterwards.

The codes are like this. The FeatureClass I used here are just points with X and Y coordinates plus few additional information. Points will be extracted via Python Script tool (ArcToolBox).

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
shp = inPointShape
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(shp, ["SHAPE@XY"])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["X","Y"])
```

This doesn't cause an error but no values are passed.

However, when I print the array (the SHAPE@XY) it shows as below.

> [([141.20304792,  39.71085087],) ([141.03026594,  39.69363465],)
>    ([141.7986943 ,  39.29263103],) ([140.95115842,  39.23922211],)]

By avoiding "SHAPE@XY" and converting to DataFrame works fine as shown below. But I want to do this by including "SHAPE@XY" as well.

```
fieldNames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, item in enumerate(fieldNames):
    if item.upper() == "SHAPE":
        continue
    df[str(item)] = arr[str(item)]
```

Is there anyway to extract "SHAPE@XY"?

Comment: Additional note for study. I just realized that I should have used arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(shp, ["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"]) in the first place. Then I just convert it to df=pd.DataFrame(arr). In the beginning I wrote as (shp,["SHAPE@X"],["SHAPE@Y"]) for function argument, and this made me confuse. It was a simple mistake. However, extracting "SHAPE@XY" would be done by BERA's answer. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the numpy Array, use [pd.DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and the [da.SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

fc = r'C:\Default.gdb\adress1'
fieldlist = ['SHAPE@XY']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fieldlist), columns=fieldlist)
df[['X','Y']] = df['SHAPE@XY'].apply(pd.Series) #Split XY tuple into separate columns
```

Or use SHAPE@X, SHAPE@Y and you dont need to split the SHAPE@XY tuple

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and quick response. After writing this question I saw an article about SearchCursor and it seems it works better than the FeatureClassToNumPyArray. Changing the fieldlist to SHAPE@X and SHAPE@Y seem to separate the columns, and works fine as I wanted. However, this helped me a lot. Thanks again.